# How can I change the colour of my button linked to a drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have this Button in my Relative Layout:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/gpsButton"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="GPS"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

It is linked to this shade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
    <stroke android:width="2sp" android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

My question is how can I change the colour from the button in my activity?

I've tried it but the app crashed -.- 
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.reli);
                        GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) relLayout.getBackground();
                        bgShape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
```

What do I wrong? I don't understand how to do this with the view.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: **1** - This `GradientDrawable bgShape` makes no sense to me. This `ShapeDrawable bgShape` would be more senseful. **2** - You start with a red color (`<solid android:color="#FF0000"/>`). If you started with a white color (`<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>`), it would be easy to change the color of that drawable. I show it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24166204/2649012

Comment: post your stacktrace!!

Comment: @DerGolem I can only start with a red colour sorry...

Comment: You can change it on the fly, as soon as the app starts.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented it like @G.T. has posted it.

Comment: Which is more or less what I tried to show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily change the background color of your `Button` programatically by adding a color filter. For that, set a white background in the XML file. Then, to make the button red, you can do this:

```
gpsButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

The `red` and `white` will be multiplied which will result as `red`. Of course, you can replace the `Color.RED` by the color you want.